# How to manage the line spacing in UILabel vertically

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I am implementing a `UILabel` vertically.

The text has custom line spacing in iOS 7 & 8 with [image]autolayout storyboard.Please check attachment.
[image]

Comment: What is your question. I see two images that are very similar. What is it you are trying to do and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to set dynamic spacing in label line between character vertically.Like We have BK String  in vertically. I want to specing in between BK.

Answer (score 0):

An option (probably not the best one, but it's something) is to have two separate labels for the B and the K and set the position and height for each so they appear to be the same.

With the right values they wouldn't have any gap between them, and line up on the edges, so there would be no queue that they're separate elements on the screen. And you could set the B to be bottom aligned and the K to be top aligned and use the label margins to get the desired spacing between them.